# Displaymemberpath of joined table

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I've got a linq query which returns a joined table of tblprofessionals and contacts (every professional is a contact, contact holds names, dob, etc and professional holds professional specific data, site, department, etc).

```
var asdf = (from a in dbContext.tblProfessionals
    join b in dbContext.contacts on a.contactId equals b.id
    select a);
```

So this should in theory return id, contactid, profsite, profdept, fname, lname, dob, etc.

My question is, how do set up the displaymemberpath to display the text in the combobox to be contacts.fname or contacts.lname. I've tried simply putting

```
DisplayMemberPath="contacts.firstname"
```

but this doesn't do anything and gives me this error

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'contacts' property not found on 'object' ''tblProfessional_1A2B2A1807FB8D48C805B985C726109DE29EF14983C5E9CE6564073CA9BB6C7F' (HashCode=54488246)'. BindingExpression:Path=contacts.firstname; DataItem='tblProfessional_1A2B2A1807FB8D48C805B985C726109DE29EF14983C5E9CE6564073CA9BB6C7F' (HashCode=54488246); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

That makes sense because obviously firstname isn't in tblProfessionals but I've joined the tables so it should be in the joined table ... so can I and if I can, how do I make this happen?

Comment: Try this: - `DisplayMemberPath= asdf.firstname`

Comment: I get the same error - BindingExpression path error: 'asdf' property not found on object etc.

Comment: Okay just saw your DS properly, I think `asdf.contact.firstname` should give you correct output.

Comment: No the contacts table contains firstname, I've joined it in the linq statement, or at least I think I have.

Comment: Yup since asdf only holds `tblprofessionals`, but you are looking for firstname which is under `contact`, `asdf.contact.firstname` should work or better extract an anonymous type from query.

Comment: If I set `cbProf.DisplayMemberPath = asdf.contact.firstname` it gives me an error because asdf doesn't have a contact field. If I set it to `DisplayMemberPath = "asdf.contact.firstname"` it doesn't work again with the same error in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join the profs and the contacts but only put the profs (`a`) into `asdf`.

So do the following:

```
var asdf = (from a in dbContext.tblProfessionals
join b in dbContext.contacts on a.contactId equals b.id
select new { ContactId = a.contactId, FirstName = b.firstname, LastName = b.lastname});
```

Now you've put one property of the Profs and two from the contacts into an anonymous type in variable `asdf`.
Then you can do:

```
cbProf.DisplayMemberPath = asdf.FirstName;
```

Comment: I eventually went with something similar to this, created that anonymous type then put it into a Professionals item which I then put into the list to show in the combobox with a field Professionals.Name and set DMP = "Name" which worked.